# android string equals returns false but they are equal

Tags: android, string, equals

I've written this code:

```
Log.d("DE", p1.pId);
```

and I know `p1.pId` is `"123"` (it's String and all)

I then do:

```
if (p1.pId.equals("123"))
```

and it's always false.

Eclipse debugging tooltip is EXACTLY THE SAME.

I've noticed that via Log.d though I don't see `123` but `123` with 1 slashed somehow (like a special character). I've tried copy pasting in Notepad++ only to get `??123`, when I paste in notepad I get smaller text.

Instead of `123` I get (maybe) `ff fe ff fe ff fe 31` in hex.

Please check this picture: http://img821.imageshack.us/img821/8616/foox.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string has Unicode byte order marks at the beginning. They need to be stripped off. If you show the code where is `p1.pId` coming from, perhaps we can explain how it can be fixed there.